# How to place content on the right side of a column with css grid

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have a css grid with 6 columns with two contents:

one from column 2 to 5 and another one from column 5 to column 7

and this is what I get on firefox:

[image]

although it looks as I expect to look, on other browser look different, here is a example on chorme (but it looks the same in all browsers):

[image]

How can I make that the pink content look like firefox in all browsers:

Here is my actual code:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 7;
}

.content {
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

any suggestion in order to make all browsers look like firefox?

Comment: try minmax(0,1fr) instead of 1fr

Answer (score 0):

`justify-self` should do it

```
.sidebar {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  justify-self: end;
}
```